# ¿como puedo hacer para que while repita la variable 'name' cierto numero de veces?

Tags: python, python-3.x, while

```
def fun ():
    re_ingresar = True
    num_nombres = int(input('cuantos nombres vas a escribir?'))
    while (re_ingresar):
        nombre = input('escribe un nombre:')
#el output te repite 'escribe un nombre' infinidad de veces,
#pero estoy tratando que sea solo 3 veces osea (num_nombres veces).
```

lo que intento es esto:

```
def fun ():
    re_ingresar = True
    num_nombres = int(input('cuantos nombres vas a escribir?'))
    while (re_ingresar):
        name = input('escribe un nombre:')

        if repeticion == num_nombres #la variable 'repeticion' es un ejemplo y no se me ocurre como encontrarla
                                     #repeticion = numero de veces que la variable name se repite.
        re_ingresar = False
```

Mi pregunta es: ¿Es posible darle un valor a la variable 'repeticion' .Si no es asi, que me aconsejarian?

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Te recomiendo usar `for i in range(num_nombres)` dado que es mas acorde al problema planteado.
Si por alguna razón estuvieras forzado a usar `while` define la variable `i = 0` fuera del loop e incrementala en cada iteración. Cuando se cumpl que `i == num_nombres` setea `re_ingresar` como `False` para salir del loop.

```
def fun (): 
    re_ingresar = True 
    num_nombres = int(input('cuantos nombres vas a escribir?')) 
    i = 0
    while (re_ingresar): 
        name = input('escribe un nombre:') 
        if i == num_nombres:
            re_ingresar = False
        i += 1
```